# How to set screen resolution to 1366 x 768 in Windows 10 - when this option is not available to choose?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, resolution

I have a new hard disk with Windows 10 installed - I had to change my previous one due to bad sectors on it and it was unable to run the OS.

I have a Samsung monitor with a recommended resolution of 1366 x 768; but in Windows 10, this option (*1366 x 768 for screen resolution*) is not available - by default is selected *1200x800* - by selecting he other approximate option - which is 1600 x 900 IIRC, the monitor shows an alert saying that the optimal/recommended screen resolution is 1366 x 768.

I had search about this issue and the solutions are:

- Search updates of the drivers (*via Windows Update*) - It says that I already have installed the most updated drivers.
- Uninstall drivers - I can't do this since I really don't know which one and I don't think this *is* needed.
- Search about ways to set this resolution via cmd - it doesn't convince me try by this way.

How can Windows 10 recognize the screen's resolution and allow to select the screen resolution?

Any advice about how can I improve this question are welcome.

---

Here are some information about my monitor and the CD/driver I found:

- Monitor Samsung - model 943SNXPLUS
- Model Code: LS19MYYKFNA/ZM
- Color Display Unit  -  Type No: MC19WS
- Samsung MC19WS

CD/Driver:

- SAMSUNG SyncMaster - 2. Monitor Driver
- Serial code: BN59-0095A-02

When I play the CD, is shows the user manual and installation guide - which is open in the browser - , but I have to check further, due I couldn't find the driver itself; by reading the user manual, it shows the link for get he latest version of the driver, but it search in the same CD and says: file not found.

These are the values found in the "Details" tab of the Microsoft Basic Display Adapter:

> PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03D0&SUBSYS_CB8410DE&REV_A2
>
> PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03D0&SUBSYS_CB8410DE
>
> PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03D0&CC_030000
>
> PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_03D0&CC_0300

This is the screenshot:

[image: Details values]

This is the model of my PC:

[image: Windows 10 Pro 64 bits AMD Athlon(tm)]

Comment: Trusting the drivers that Windows Update provides is likely not the way to go here. You should (if possible) download drivers/software for both your specific monitor and graphics card from their respective manufacturer's websites. If this is a laptop, you should look for appropriate drivers on the laptop manufacturer's website.

Comment: @Anaksunaman thank you for your answer. It is a desktop PC. How can I check the manufacturer's screen and get the monitor specifications? - I'm not good in PC maintenance :) - I do remember that there was a program that read the PC specification details like RAM, motherboard, but, I'm not sure.

Comment: You just need the manufacturer website and the models. These should be in stickers found on the monitor and computer.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes As harrymc points out, the best method to identify the monitor brand and model is from the stickers (usually on the back of the monitor or PC). If you need a utility, you may want to try the free version of [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) (or similar software), though I am not certain how accurate it may be in identifying devices assuming generic drivers are installed.

Comment: @harrymc thanks to your comment I now remember I have some CD's of the monitor - I hope those are the drivers - also, the monitor has a sticker in its back, so, probably such information will point to the right direction. I'll check and update the question with more details once I proceed. Thank you too, Anaksunaman.

Comment: Driver for graphics controls resolution selection. Post the make and specific model of the PC please.

Comment: 1366 x 768 is a mystery, don't by 1366 x 768 monitors. 1360 x 768 is commonly the best you can achieve.

Comment: @jw_ I didn't know that. I hope that once the driver is installed correctly, I can select 1360x768, then :) Thank you.

Comment: Hello. Have you checked if your graphic card drivers are correct? It is possible you have a chipset/video adapter that is incompatible with windows 10. You will be unable to choose many resolutions.  To check: Right click on the start logo. Click on Open Device Manager. Click on the arrow next to Graphic Card. If it is written Microsoft Basic Display Adapter: your drivers are incorrrect.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Windows Update pulls the most recent WHQL drivers available from the developer, so the driver version Windows Update finds is the most recent version available from that developer. This being said, GPU drivers are a bit different due to the customizations made to the drivers by the PC manufacturer _(applies only to the integrated graphics on the CPU & the original GPU that came with the PC, but if the PC is DIY built, this doesn't apply)_, so if the GPU has custom drivers from the PC manufacturer, generic drivers from the developer usually cannot even be installed, even if newer.

Comment: @NatsuKage you're right, it is written Microsoft Basic Display Adapter and I installed the driver, but is is not recognized due isn't in x64. I don't know what to do now :(

Comment: Can you please post your computer model so we can help you? Also, to help, please double click on the item written Microsoft Basic Display Adapter > Select the Details Tab > Property > Hardware ID  Right click on that string and copy paste it here. It'll look something like: PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_67DF&SUBSYS_E3661DA2&REV_E7.

Comment: @NatsuKage question edited. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Ah...the nForce 430 chipset... This integrated video card isn't compatible with Windows 10. You might need to install a video card compatible with Windows 10. I will post a possible solution though in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer uses the nForce 430 chipset, which uses an older 6150se Geforce video chip. There is no windows 10 driver but a win7/8 driver may work:

https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/82758

This is an older Win7 64bit driver that is compatible with the 6150se. This will allow you to choose resolutions such as 1360/1366x768.

Comment: Your spot on. The videocard doesn't have to proper driver. The basic driver Microsoft automatically installs is too limited to control the monitor properly.

Comment: Thank you, Natsu Kage, your answer solved my problem and I'll reward your answer. Thank you, everyone! :)